# Elixir remove common elements from two lists

Tags: elixir

I want to remove the elements found in list b from list a. 
The list a is printing [1,2,3,4] after execution of this code.

```
defmodule Test do
def listing do
    a = [1,2,3,4]
    b = [3,4,5,6]

    Enum.each b, fn elemB ->
        a = Enum.filter(a, fn(x) -> x != elemB == true end)
        #IO.inspect a
    end 
    IO.inspect a
end
end

Test.listing()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need that outer `Enum.each`, you can do it with a single filter by enumerating over `a` and checking each element to see if it is a member of `b`:

```
Enum.filter(a, fn el -> !Enum.member?(b, el) end)
```

Outputs:

```
[1, 2]
```

It looks like with your current solution you are trying to modify `a` but that won't work because Elixir is functional and the function can't have side effects; the `a` inside your `each` is not the same as the `a` that is the original list.

Comment: You can also flip the condition if you prefer this wording: `Enum.reject(a, fn el -> Enum.member?(b, el) end)` But note the `MapSet` answer.

Comment: Right, I was just pointing out why the original code wasn't working.

Answer (score 15):

Both ways presented in other answers at the moment (`Enum.filter` and `--`) will work well on small lists. But, lists are large, they are very inefficient.

If lists are large, better to use `MapSet`:

```
MapSet.difference(MapSet.new(a), MapSet.new(b)) |> MapSet.to_list
```

It spends some time to convert both lists to MapSets, and then to convert result back to list, but these operations are `n log(n)`, while `Enum.filter` and substraction (`--`) here are quadratic.

I've prepared a [gist with benchmarks](https://gist.github.com/denispeplin/99047e34b0974b00116f335651d551d6).

Summary: for very short list substraction is fastest, for lists around 100  elements long `Enum.filter` is fastest, and for lists around 1000 elements `MapSet.difference` is fastest. It is hundreds times faster on lists with 100K elements.

Actually, on lists this size `MapSet.difference` works 0.08 seconds, `Enum.filter` 16 seconds, and substraction 44 seconds.

**UPDATE**: `Dogbert` asked me to also benchmark Erlang's `ordsets`:

```
:ordsets.subtract(:ordsets.from_list(a), :ordsets.from_list(b)) |> :ordsets.to_list
```

It works faster than `MapSet`, especially on mid-size lists about 1000 records long (`MapSet` is about `1.4` times slower).

Comment: Could you also add `ordsets` to the benchmark? The Erlang documentation recommends using it instead of `--`. `:ordsets.subtract(:ordsets.from_list(a), :ordsets.from_list(b)) |> :ordsets.to_list`.

Comment: Also, List to MapSet conversion is not linear but O(n log n) because inserting a value in a Map in Erlang is O(log n).

Comment: @Dogbert, I did it, please check results.

Comment: thanks! Looks like maps are probably fast enough now to not have to bother with using ordsets for this task. I remember maps being much slower than ordsets when I tried them the first time (~OTP 18).

Comment: @Dogbert,  is there a more effective way for doing this when the elements arent exactly the same but have a common key? other than `Enum.reject(list1, fn(l1) -> Enum.any?(list2, fn(l2) -> l2.id == l1.id end) end)` ?

Comment: Surprise everyone! I re-ran the benchmark on Elixir 1.12.1/OTP24 and the performance characteristics have shifted significantly: https://gist.github.com/iStefo/d83bc2737168daf6faf7fa0d2fea2ce2

Now, list subtraction (`--`) is always the fastest (or on-par), regardless of the list lengths!

This is in line with the "Retired Myths" section from the erlang efficiency guide: http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/retired_myths.html#myth--list-subtraction-------operator--is-slow

Answer (score 14):

You can also use the `--` operator (https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#--/2)

```
iex> [1, 2, 3] -- [1, 2]
[3]
```

Comment: This is handy but keep in mind `[1, 2, 3] -- [1, 2, 4]` will only return `[3]` and not `[3, 4]`.

Comment: @originalhat Yes, as per the original question the result is a set difference, not a symmetric difference.

Answer (score 3):

In Elixir >= v1.4 there is the function List.myers_difference, so you can do

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [3,4,5,6]
List.myers_difference(a,b) |> 
Keyword.get(:del)

[1,2]
```

doc to List.myers_difference

https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html#myers_difference/2

Answer (score 1):

Following to @Tyler answer,
You can make your code clearer using `Enum.reject` instead of `Enum.filter`:

```
 Enum.reject(a, fn el -> Enum.member?(b, el) end)
```

This will give the same result as:

```
Enum.filter(a, fn el -> !Enum.member?(b, el) end)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on elixir but you can try something like this

```
Enum.reject(a, fn x -> Enum.member?(b, x) end)
```