# Erlang maps or gb_sets

Tags: erlang, containers, erlang-otp

I need set of elements with maximum performance of lookup/insert operations.

What is better to use from performance point of view:

```
put(Key, Set) ->
    Set#{ Key => true }.
has(Key, Set) ->
    maps:get(Key, Set, false).
```

Or

```
put(Key, Set) ->
    gb_sets:add_element(Key, Set).
has(Key, Set) ->
    gb_sets:is_element(Key, Set).
```

May be some other better solution exists?

Comment: Both of them have O(n log n) insert/lookup. The performance likely depends on the size of the keys and the types of the keys. Your best bet would be to benchmark against the kind and size of keys you expect.

Comment: Constant does matter in this case. I'm can do performance test by myself but I believe that this already done. If no, I will answer this question after my own measures.

Comment: @Dogbert O(n log n) is typo I suppose. O(log n). But I've also made some measurements, looks like maps are hashmap and have O(1) lookup complexity.

Comment: Yep, I meant `O(log n)`. Erlang Maps are not HashMaps, they're a tree like data structure (can't find direct reference but I believe they are HAMT) which makes lookups O(log n). The constant does matter and its value depends on the number of keys and the types of keys. See this question for an example where the performance of Map vs OrdSet varies by the number of keys: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46618208/320615.